# How to Change the font for org-date face in org-table context?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, fonts, org-table

I like to have a variable font everywhere I can, but some things like tables in `org-mode` or the `org-agenda` itself look a little wonky that way, and I get around it by configuring specific fixed width fonts in these areas.

I’ve already set a fixed width font for the `org-table` face, but dates inside the table still showed up with a variable width font. I changed this too by adding this configuration to my `init.el`:

```lisp
(custom-theme-set-faces
 'user
  '(org-date ((t (:family "Source Code Pro" :height 120)))))
```

I really prefer variable width fonts and think that dates also look and read better that way if they are outside of a table, but I don’t know how to set the font used by a face depending on its context.

How can I change my config so that my custom `org-date` face only triggers when the date is inside an `org-table`?